# Where does the Sci-Fi term "Tyran" come from?

Tags: history-of, science-fiction-genre

Restating my question, In most of my history with Sci-fi games (Gears,40k,etc) and even on a lackluster sci fi wiki that Tyran is a human (Sci-Fi wiki entry: Tyran-A being who is of Human descent but is not truly human or a half human being/Half Human Descendent of the Human race) and now learning that Tyran is not really mainstream in science fiction, where did this term come from.
Note: A entry from a dictionary style Wikipedia stating that Tyran in English and French is a word shorten from the Old Latin term Tyrant(dictators).

Comment: I think that"Terran" refers to Earth, but Tyran probably is meant to have a different implication altogether.

Comment: It may be so in many works, but I don't think "the majority" is really true.

Comment: I've never heard of Tyran. Is it really that common?

Comment: Duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116820/what-is-the-origin-of-the-word-terrans-when-referring-to-humanoids-and-other-e ?

Comment: In a way this question contains two distinct questions, since it involves two different words. So that would be another possible reason to close it, unless the references to "Terrans" is removed. But then Richard's answer doesn't make sense...

Comment: yes thanks you all, but I had noticed tyran more than terran, like gears of war and warhammer 40k, the core characters are humans referred to as tyrans and fought and allied with the native American  communist like kashkur/gorasni people also humans and humans are named tyran as a whole for each game respectively

Comment: Also if it means more, I wish to know if anyone has the knowledge of the earliest use of Tyran in terms of Humans.

Comment: 'Tyran' isn't a common sci-fi term in english, so looking for the earliest usage may be difficult and unrelated to subsequent usages.  I think its just random chance that multiple franchises used the same aberration of the word 'Terrian' .

Comment: The word "Tyran" in Gear of War isn't interchangable with "Terran". Tyrans are **citizens of the nation-state of Tyrus**; http://gearsofwar.wikia.com/wiki/Tyran

Comment: In WH40K. Humans are called _Terrans_ because they're from _Terra_, aka Earth. [Tyran](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Tyran) is the world where humans first encountered Hive Fleet Behemoth, and where the name **Tyranid** was derived.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this might be a possible answer.

[image]

> The first installment of Asimov's *Tyrann* was the cover story in the fourth issue of *Galaxy Science Fiction* in 1951. The novel was issued in book form later that year as *The Stars Like Dust*.

The human-descended bad hats in this Asimov story came from the planet Tyrann. Perhaps someone adopted it as the basis of the term "Tyran"?

Comment: That would be my guess, seeing as Asimov's is the only Tyran(n) I ever heard of. https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v01n04_1951-01