# Where did using "Luna" as the future name for the moon come from?

Tags: history-of, names

Besides Latin, of course. It seems to be very common to refer to the (typically colonized) moon as "Luna" in [sci-fi works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luna_City). Did authors independently decide to use the Latin name? Or did someone originate this, and future usages were a reference/tribute? Why do future humans use a name that current humans generally don't?

Comment: Using Latin names for bodies in the solar system is a general Sci Fi trope in and of itself.

Comment: This question may be closed as being too broad because of the genre wide basis. You might want to narrow it down to a single universe or to a single work to keep the question open. It's also not very clear what you're asking. Are you asking if humans in the future prefer the term *Luna* or if someone once used it and future people have kept using it?NB: I haven't flagged it because I'm unsure.

Comment: I'm wondering why authors use it, and why they selected a name that is currently obsolete for use in the future. I guess it's just the Latin trope that @Terriblefan mentioned, good enough for me, thanks!

Comment: @JHZ "Why do future humans use a name that current humans generally don't?" An Anglo-centric thinking is occurring. The Romantic languages and surprisingly some non-Roman languages use words like Luna or Lune. And, albeit rarely, you will hear English speakers use the term. In fact, growing up in a bilingual province in a bilingual country, I was surprised when I discovered in adulthood that Luna _was not_ the name of The Moon (in the same way we call "The Planet" Earth, I thought Luna was the moon's name.).

Comment: I'd say it had something to do with the Soviet moon probes being called Luna (since this is what the Moon, or any moon, is called in Russian). Obviously, I have no evidence.

Comment: Check out the similar (and complementary) question on Sol for our sun: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/92149/4516

Comment: @Lan I don't think so, the works I've read are written in English. In French, the equivalent would be using "Luna" instead of "la lune" - they're much more similar, but not the same word.

Comment: @Lan In fact, the adjective even in English is *Lunar* (as in *Lunar Eclipse*)

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/116820/4918 "What is the origin of the word “terrans” when referring to humanoids and other earth-related things?"

Comment: I don't quite understand it either. The proper greek mythology name for that particular celestial body would be Selene.

Comment: @Lan - Wait... Its not the name of the moon?? I thought it was too... I must find out what it is now.

Comment: Apparently, its just called "The Moon". My life is a lie. http://www.universetoday.com/120087/what-is-the-moons-real-name/

Comment: "The moon."
"Which moon?"
"The moon of the third planet from the sun."
"Which sun?"
This system is better as long as we assume the Romantic languages will die off before we start space exploration.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The reason *why* people in a science-fiction future would call the moon Luna is explained in Seeds' answer. If, like most people today, you only know about one moon, you can just call it the moon. If there are lots of moons that play a part in your life—you read about them in the papers, visit them on vacations, go to work on them, etc.—and if all the *other* moons have proper names like Phobos, Callisto, Titan, etc., then Earth's moon needs a proper name too, and Luna is a natural choice.

But you also seem to be asking about the *origin* of calling the moon Luna in science fiction. According to the [Historical Dictionary of Science Fiction](https://sfdictionary.com/view/353), it seems to have started with this line from [Raymond Z. Gallun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Z._Gallun)'s novelette ["The Lunar Chrysalis"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?85386) in [*Amazing Stories*, September 1931](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56669+c), p. 528, column 2 (available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/AmazingStoriesV06N06193109#page/n49/mode/2up)):

> I never regretted my decision to be one of the first men to visit Luna.

Comment: A great answer to an overly broad question.

Comment: It's also interesting to note that in `A Voyage to the Moon (1827) by George Tucker.` Lunar is used to refer to many things; as the title indicates, the Lunar world is still called the moon. (he does refer to `Luna firma` at one point)

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks!

Comment: @Seeds But that's not noteworthy, that just normal English usage now and in 1827: [“lunar” is the English adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectivals_and_demonyms_of_astronomical_bodies#Moons) for things related to/from the Moon, as opposed to something like “moonar” which isn't a real word. That's why we call probes that go to the Moon “lunar probes”.

Comment: Luna is the roman goddess of the moon. So, effectively, people started calling the moon that more than 2000 years ago and then at some point didn't call it that for a long time. Only when the need arose that there are more than one moon and moon became the general designation for any natural satellite around a planet, our moon needed a new (old) name.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I thought it was noteworthy that despite the fact that the the adjective form of Luna was used extensively, the proper name took so long to become common use, even in fiction. As you say, it is/was common usage; but common usage isn't always common in fantastic fiction. :)

Comment: @Seeds Ah, I see what you mean!

Answer (score 64):

Primarily, 'moon' is too general. Luna refers to Earth's moon, not other moons, of other planets. People outside SF&F have no reason to think about any other moons, for the most part, so saying 'The Moon' is distinct, and understood. In a setting where you are talking about other planets and THEIR moons, saying 'The Moon' is meaningless, particularly between people from different planets.

Comment: It's interesting that in works I've read/watched, Earth-residents never refer to Luna as "the moon", in the same way that someone on Long Island or in Palo Alto would refer to "the city" and mean separate fairly unambiguous things, even though they have proper names ("New York" and "San Francisco"). But maybe I haven't read the right works. Or maybe that would be confusing for present-day readers!

Comment: But by the same token, "earth" is too general too, yet in a lot of prominent Sci-Fi people from planets all over the galaxy don't call the Earth "Terra".

Comment: @Michael: you'd have to be one of those chauvinistic Terrans to not refer to the planet by its proper designation -- Sol III. :-P

Comment: @Michael I'm not sure if "Earth" is too vague.  It's not the same as "Planet".  We haven't defined any other Earth's,  but there are a lot of moons.  I've also read books where they do call Earth "Terra" or some other similar variation.

Comment: There's a great bit of a dialogue about this in the *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* episode "Valiant", when a character named Chief Collins mentions that she's from the Moon. Jake tries to laugh about how his grandfather calls Luna "the Moon" ("as if it's the only one"), and Collins replies that no one who's actually from Moon ever calls it anything but "Moon".

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all.

Comment: @JoeBlow Assuming that at least one of the OP's questions is meant in-universe, it does.

Comment: @ruakh I did wonder whether that statement was meant to be interpreted as "the only moon *of Earth*" - to imply that they've built or imported another by that period in history. Probably not - but it's fun to imagine the showrunners trolling us lowly viewers.

Comment: If “Luna“ uniquely refers to Earth's moon, I wonder what the general term for “lunar“ (lunar surface etc.) would be. How are things on other moons called?

Comment: I always thought "Moon" was just Earth's natural satellite's name, and the common noun "moon" (to refer to planets' natural satellites) came from the Moon's name. :/

Comment: @Michael in a lot of prominent Sci-Fi people don't call the Moon *Luna* either, and conversely *Terra* is indeed found in other sci-fi, likewise *Sol* for the particular sun that is the called *the Sun* by most English-speaking Terrans. *Terra* is a bit of a further stretch though in that other moons are called *moons* but other planets are not called *earths* except figuratively, so using *Luna* and *Sol* but not *Terra* is as reasonable a choice as any.

Comment: @FelixDombek I we go by analogy to the other words, "terran" is used almost exclusively to refer to our planet. So by extension, "lunar" must pertain to only our moon, and "solar" to our sun.

Answer (score 30):

> (...) use a name that current humans generally don't?

Wow, quite a claim there!
Let's see:

- 427 million of native Spanish speakers call our moon "Luna".
- 160 million of native Russian speakers call our moon "Луна".
- 65 million of native Italian speakers call our moon "Luna".
- 24 million of native Romanian speakers call our moon "Lună".
- 9 million of native Bulgarian speakers call our moon "Луна".

So we have **685+ million people that say, *exactly*, "Luna"** when talking about our moon.
And:

- 230 million of native Portuguese speakers call our moon "Lua".
- 80 million of native French speakers call our moon "Lune".
- 4 million of native Catalan speakers call our moon "Lluna".
- 2 million of native Galician speakers call our moon "Lúa".

A total of about **1 billion people closer to "Luna" than to "Moon"**.

How does "Moon" compare?

- 340 million native English speakers saying "Moon"
- 40 million native Hausa speakers saying "Moon"
- 28 million native Filipino speakers saying "Moon"
- 17 million native Somali speakers saying "Moon"
- 2.5 million native Slovenian speakers saying "Moon"

So that's 425+ million people saying "Moon" today.
And:

- 95 million native German speakers saying "Mond"
- 23 native Dutch speakers saying "Maan"
- 10 million native Swedish speakers saying "Måne"
- 7 million native Afrikaans speakers saying "Maan"
- 5.5 million native Danish speakers saying "Månen"
- 5 million native Norwegian speakers saying "Månen"

A total of 570 million people that may be closer to saying "Moon" than "Luna" (I say maybe because e.g. "Månen" is closer to "money" than to "moon", but I included it anyway).

If we include second languages, the numbers are about 1.3 billion people for "Moon" and 1.5 billion people for "Luna".

So **it turns out that humans *do* use "Luna" as the name for our moon**. More than Chinese "月亮", more than English "Moon". This and the "clarity" argument given in the other answers may be the main reasons for some future Earth using "Luna" as the name for our moon.

Comment: [Can't comment as anonymous, someone feel free to move this to a comment of walen's answer.]
As one of the 9 million Bulgarian speakers, I can tell you that the general word "луна" that means "moon" and can be applied to any other planet is not necessarily the same as the Latin proper name Luna. The stress in the Bulgarian word is on the last syllable, in the Latin word it is on the first. When used as a proper name, I guess officially it is again with the stress on the last syllable, but I can easily see the Latin pronunciation becoming official in the future in order to distinguish between t

Comment: Hi, anonymous. Before including Russian (and Romanian) in the first list, I compared it against the Spanish pronunciation [here](https://translate.google.com/#es/ru/luna) and I didn't see any significant differences between them. It's true that, since Google didn't have the audio for Bulgarian, I just took for granted that the Bulgarian pronunciation would be the same as Russian; I'm sorry if I was mistaken. That would put you in the second list, though, so still closer to "Luna" than to "Moon" :)

Comment: It would be interesting to add info about the moon/luna in other indoeuropean languages (hindi and bengali, for example, since these languages have a lot of native speakers). as well as other major groups (arabic, for example).

Comment: Hi @TZakrevskiy. If you're interested, I got most translations from here: http://www.indifferentlanguages.com/words/moon. There are a handful of common roots in there that I'd love to know more about! Sadly, as much as I like languages and to delve into the origin of words, I don't know Asian and Arabic languages well enough to include that info.

Comment: Since this answer is largely about pronunciation, could we get a Romanization of 月亮?

Comment: According to Google, 月亮 is transcribed as "Yuèliàng".

Comment: For people who don't know pinyin, a *rough* approximation of "yuèliàng" would be "y'weh l'yang," with "eh" somewhere between the "eh" in "meh" and "ay," depending on your accent, and "ang" like in "manga." I know they say "yey-ay" in Avatar, and it makes me cry.

Comment: As an English-speaker, the first thought that popped in my mind in response to this question was "La Luna El Por El Aqua" from a poem way back in elementary school.  I very well may have mangled that, but it did trigger the thought that this was a very english-centric question.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson That may be ["Media luna" by Federico García Lorca](https://garcialorca.wikispaces.com/Antolog%C3%ADa#La%20luna%20va), a Spanish poet. It starts with the verse "La luna va por el agua" ... But we're really going offtopic here :)

Comment: But of course, the works I'm referring to are in English, and the characters are speaking in English. For example, in _The Expanse_, most of the Holden and Amos are Americans (or what passes for that in the future), but use "Luna". It would be the equivalent of a French work using "Moon" as the proper name in the future.

Comment: I am spanish and hear "prime time" way more often than "horario de máxima audiencia". In japanese ミルク (from english milk) is used very often despite having a native japanese word for milk: 牛乳. There was a time when using the french word Fin instead of the film's language word for The End was popular. These are know as loan words or loan expresions. It is not a strech to imagine a future where Luna is a loan word in english taken from spanish.

Comment: So what are Spanish people going to call the Earth's Moon once they live on other planets?  "Moon"?